# ClassCastException for LayoutParams from Android itself

Tags: android, android-layout

here's a problem i fought the whole laste night with and still didnt fix it.

```
08-12 08:23:09.617 22562-22562/de.airdevelopments.goetheapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: de.airdevelopments.goetheapp, PID: 22562
                                                                          java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1489)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

The Exception doesnt tell me, what I did wrong, cause the call is kind a subcall from an android class itself. Very bad. This all started after I started my rework for the GraphicalUserInterface... I can't find the problem. Does someone of you got experience with that? What could cause that? I am not accessing LayoutParams on any object myself.

Note: The whole error appears in a TabbedActivity. The first time I go through the Tabs, everything works clearly awesome. But when I go back from the third third Tab to the first (which then gets reloaded, I guess) the error appears.

If you need any code, please let me know, cause I dont know, what code I should post here.

Code: http://pastebin.com/yhaZbJB5

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your *code* please.

Comment: What do you need? Activity + all xml fragments? Or is the first enough, cause I think, that is causing the problem.

Comment: Post your *activity* code.

Comment: Messy code pasted, sorry about that.

Comment: if(newsListLayout != null)
            {
                ViewGroup parent = ((ViewGroup) newsListLayout.getParent());
 
                if(parent != null)
                    parent.removeView(newsListLayout);
 
                return newsListLayout;
            } (Line 535) Thats the bad guy, but when I remove this, I get another error. A little Question: Do I have to create a new Question or can I kind a like change / advance the topic?

Comment: Shot in the dark here but I wonder if the casting exception is caused by trying to cast `ViewPager.LayoutParams` incorrectly to the `ViewPager.LayoutParams` in the v4 support library? try removing this import `import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;` and then let your IDE import the the `ViewPager` but don't select the support one

Comment: Hmm. Good Idea but theres no version independet import for me there, only v4.

Comment: However, I remove the mentioned code and fixed the other error, works fine now. Thanks for all your help guys!